# Need to use cntrl z in shell script

Tags: shell

My requirement is to go to many servers and execute the same commands in all servers.
The problem is when I execute one such command like `rpm -qa |grep qli`, I am able to get the output, but the system hangs after that output. So I need to manually give cntrl +z to kill the process. So because of this I am unable to telnet to other servers.

My script goes like this:

```
while read server
do

  echo $server

  if [ $? = 0 ]; then

   /home/telnet-client $server user password " rpm -qa | grep qlinux"  //sometimes this command hangs

-------
-------  //how to give cntrl +z so that it does not hangs in the same server 

   fi
done < /home/a  //list of server ip
```

Answer (score 0):

Start the process in the background, and redirect the output to a file. Then delay for some time, and kill the process. `cat` the output:

```
rpm -qa | grep qlinux > output & sleep 5; pkill rpm; cat output
```